How to capture browser audio and send the mediaStream to server for speech to text?
I have a web app in which I want to capture the audio of a chrome tab which the user selects. I can get the mediaStream using navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({audio: true , video: true})
How can I send the audio from this mediaStream to a server and perform speech to text and get the transcribed text back?
I've been stuck on this for 2 weeks. I would really appreciate if someone can help me out!
Thanks!!
I tried using webRtc and websockets and have no idea what to do. Because I can't find anything about transcription or any docs related to how I can perform it in realtime on the stream captured from getDisplayMedia(). Or Is there any other way other than getDisplayMedia()

This is a very broad topic and is not answerable here in one piece.  However, If you're interested, I have an entire solution that does this, as well as handles translation between different languages, intercepts WebRTC MediaStreams for live transcription/translation of conference calls, etc.  It utilizes AWS for the transcription/translation with the rest of the code running entirely client-side with no server-side dependencies.  This code is well documented and available for licensing.  You can contact me at brad@audiopump.co.
